# In OpenERP 7.x how to give a customer read-only access through the portal to a small set of documents

Tags: openerp-7

I have been trying for a few days to figure out how to allow a set of customers to view a specific set of documents in OpenERP's knowledge management module.  The goal is to easily add access to various sets of documents to *existing* customers.  My particular use is that I deliver three different types of training sessions each of which has a set of materials in pdf format.  I would like to offer all the attendees access to those materials through OpenERP (since they are already in the system as customers).  I am *not* using the Events modules and I am not particularly interested in exploring it at this time.

Setup that I have tried:

1. Have some existing customers with at least a name and email address
2. Create a "Directory" in Knowledge->Document Management->Directories
3. Add a few pdf files in Knowledge->Documents each with the directory just created
4. Create a "Group" in Settings->Groups
5. ...  ???

I've tried various combinations of access rights, rules, users, etc. but nothing seems *simple* and nothing works exactly as I'm hoping: namely that a customer receives access through the web client to a clearly labeled menu that then shows them exactly the set of documents that they are allowed to access.

I have also tried the various "Share" features that can be done with documents, but again, they don't seem to work well for existing customers, nor so well with groups of related documents.

I have been able to get a *user* (not a customer) to get restricted access to see only a small set of the documents in the Knowledge Management system, but even there I'm having a hard time restricting that user to see *only* the documents that are in the specified directory.

I've taken a look at a number of sites (including ZestyBeanz) that describe various means of getting users to access the portal / limited features of OpenERP.

My OpenERP installation is self-hosted on Amazon so I have full control.  I have written sophisticated modules for OpenERP and I am a reasonably capable Python programmer so please feel free to get seriously technical if that would help.  I'm willing to consider writing a custom module to enable what I feel should be an obvious and easy feature, but that really seems like overkill!

To be clear: either a configuration or programming solution would be fine by me.

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Comment: It may be a programming question: I'm not sure if OpenERP allows what I want out of the box.  If someone can tell me how it allows it without programming, great, otherwise, if someone can tell me how to do it programmatically, also great :-)